# @testing-library/react-native render method timeout for simple component

Tags: react-native, unit-testing, testing-libraryreact-native

I am testing the app navigation stack, and when rendering a very basic component it times out with the below error though there is no heavy loading in the component.

Error:

```
Ran all test suites.
```

error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
nitinpiparava@Nitins-MacBook-Pro chronextapp % yarn run test
yarn run v1.22.10
$ jest
FAIL  **tests**/AppStack-test.js (11.447 s)
AppStack
✕ renders the correct screen (10007 ms)

● AppStack › renders the correct screen

```
thrown: "Exceeded timeout of 5000 ms for a test.
Use jest.setTimeout(newTimeout) to increase the timeout value, if this is a long-running test."

  21 |
  22 | describe('AppStack', () => {
> 23 |   it('renders the correct screen', async () => {
     |   ^
  24 |     const { getByText } = render(
  25 |       <NavigationContainer>
  26 |         <AppStack1 />

  at __tests__/AppStack-test.js:23:3
  at Object.<anonymous> (__tests__/AppStack-test.js:22:1)
```

**Component**

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

export const Screen1 = ({ navigation }) => (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Text>Screen 1</Text>
    <Button title='Go to Screen 2' onPress={() => navigation.push('Screen2')} />
  </View>
);

export const Screen2 = () => (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Text>Screen 2</Text>
  </View>
);

const Stack = createStackNavigator();
export const AppStack1 = () => (
  <Stack.Navigator>
    <Stack.Screen name='Screen1' component={Screen1} />
    <Stack.Screen name='Screen2' component={Screen2} />
  </Stack.Navigator>
);

const SignIn = () => (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Text>Sign In</Text>
  </View>
);

const AuthStack = () => (
  <Stack.Navigator>
    <Stack.Screen name='SignIn' component={SignIn} />
  </Stack.Navigator>
);

export default ({ isLoggedIn = true }) => (
  <NavigationContainer>
    {isLoggedIn ? <AppStack1 /> : <AuthStack />}
  </NavigationContainer>
);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

**Ject mock setup file**

```
    import 'react-native-gesture-handler/jestSetup';

jest.mock('react-native-reanimated', () => {
  const Reanimated = require('react-native-reanimated/mock');

  // The mock for `call` immediately calls the callback which is incorrect
  // So we override it with a no-op
  Reanimated.default.call = () => {};

  return Reanimated;
});

//Silence the warning: Animated: `useNativeDriver` is not supported because the native animated module is missing
jest.mock('react-native/Libraries/Animated/NativeAnimatedHelper');

jest.mock('rn-fetch-blob', () => {
  return {
    __esModule: true,
    default: {
      fs: {
        unlink: jest.fn(),
      },
    },
  };
});
```

**Jest Config**

```
"jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      ".+\\.(css|styl|less|sass|scss|png|jpg|ttf|woff|woff2)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    },
    "setupFiles": [
      "./src/__mocks__/@react-native-async-storage/setup.js"
    ],
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.jsx$": "babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.tsx$": "babel-jest"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!@react-native|react-native)"
    ]
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "react-native/@jest/create-cache-key-function": "^27.0.2"
  }
```

Comment: What version of react native and react navigation are you using?

Comment: @MajedBadawi 
"@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.11.11",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.4",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.5",

Comment: Did you setup the necessary mocks?

Comment: Yes I did In fact If I can also do snapshot testing through react-test-renderer but as soon as I use the render function from @testing-library/react-native i get this error, in my demo app it works fine

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/5.x/testing) (5.x), you need to do the following in the jest setup file:

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler/jestSetup';

jest.mock('react-native-reanimated', () => {
  const Reanimated = require('react-native-reanimated/mock');

  // The mock for `call` immediately calls the callback which is incorrect
  // So we override it with a no-op
  Reanimated.default.call = () => {};

  return Reanimated;
});

// Silence the warning: Animated: `useNativeDriver` is not supported because the native animated module is missing
jest.mock('react-native/Libraries/Animated/src/NativeAnimatedHelper');

// As of react-native@0.64.X file has moved
jest.mock('react-native/Libraries/Animated/NativeAnimatedHelper');
```

In the `jest.config.js`, try adding those to `setupFiles` where the first is the setup file you mentioned:

```
['./jestSetup.js', './node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/jestSetup.js']
```

And set [`transformIgnorePatterns`](https://jestjs.io/docs/tutorial-react-native#transformignorepatterns-customization):

```
transformIgnorePatterns: [
  'node_modules/(?!(@react-native' +
    '|react-native' +
    '|react-navigation-tabs' +
    '|react-native-reanimated' +
    '|react-native-iphone-x-helper' +
    '|@react-navigation' +    
    '|@react-navigation/stack' +
  ')/)',
]
```

Comment: I added my mock setup file in question

Comment: Can you add ``jest.config.js`` as well

Comment: added jest config as well

Comment: @Nitin the above additions work in my case

Comment: /Users/nitinpiparava/SourceCodes/chronextapp/node_modules/react-native-iphone-x-helper/index.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){import { Dimensions, Platform, StatusBar } from 'react-native';
                                                                                      ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Comment: Yes missed that, list updated

Comment: issue was calling //jest.useFakeTimers(); before test, If remove that test works fine but I get below meesage

ReferenceError: You are trying to `import` a file after the Jest environment has been torn down. From __tests__/AppStack-test.js.

Comment: I guess that's another issue, but it's mentioned in other posts if you do the research

Comment: Yes I did research to fix this issue and all suggested to use jest.useFakeTimers(); which has introduced the original issue, jest is buggy

Comment: Which part exactly is causing the issue?

Comment: jest.useFakeTimers(); if remove this line it works fine but then it gives  below meesage ReferenceError: You are trying to import a file after the Jest environment has been torn down. From __tests__/AppStack-test.js.

Comment: check this: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/6434

Comment: yes was referring to this only , the most worked solution is jest.useFakeTimers(); if w use that it creates another issue , original issue i reported

Comment: Have you tried the async await solution, or cleanup?

Comment: yes i am  using async in test case does not help

Comment: Setting the test as ``async`` is not enough, try wrapping the asynchronous part of the test in ``await act(async () => {});``